# How to load more than 5K records from a table to Datalake using in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have table that is having more than 5000 records. I am migrating these directly to cosmos db using dataflow, this is Initial/full load we are calling ....As a next step i have setup a pipeline that will migrate the incremental data from source table  to cosmos db using API's   Problem that i am facing  is the pipeline which i defined has limitation of 5000 recrods. i.e. For the incremental data that is having more than 5000 records it will fail because of limition of lookup activity in ADF. Could you please help me on this ?How to  load records more than 5000

Comment: can you add source dataset and destination dataset and image of pipeline.

Comment: Source is onpem sql server and destination is cosmos DB

Comment: Why are you using lookup activity? Share your approach

Comment: 1 step . we are loading on-prem data to datalake 2 step. from datalake to cosmos db . In the second step copying data from datalake to Cosmos DB through API we are using look up activity

Comment: What file format are you using? Just use copy activity, no need to use dataflow

Comment: While copying from datalake to cosmos DB , why can't you use copy activity?

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve] - currently you have only given a high level description, with no specifics.

Answer (score 0):

For lookup there is limitation of 5000 rows instead of lookup you can directly use copy activity to insert incremental records as **it provides upsert option which will insert record if not exist in destination as per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=data-factory#azure-cosmos-db-for-nosql-as-sink)**

[image]